# Custom home page with a single post?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

This is a question about Thematic framework. If this isn't the right place, just ignore this.

I'd like to ask how do I go about it? I copied the page template from the parent theme and renamed it to home.php and then I set it as the template for the home page. Then I added a hook to thematic_above_indexloop() in functions.php but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my action hook:

```
function show_single_post(){
   $i=0; // Initialize to Zero;
   if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   if ($i==0) {$recentpostid = $post->ID; $i=$i+1;}
   endwhile;
   endif;
   //get only the latest post
   $posts = query_posts( 'p='.$recentpostid."'");
}
add_action('thematic_above_indexloop', 'show_single_post');
```

However, if I embed that code snippet into the home.php directly, it works. There must something wrong with my action hook? I am relatively new to using hooks pls enlighten me.

Comment: Since it doesn't look like you are getting the results you need maybe you could post your question on StackExchange's sister site WordPress Answers? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I added a second answer with a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hello world function works, I have to believe that your function is the problem.

There is a simpler way to get the single latest post:

```
    function show_single_post(){
       query_posts('orderby=ID&order=desc&showposts=1');
    }

   add_action('thematic_above_indexloop', 'show_single_post');
```

I tested this with Thematic and it shows the last post on the homepage.  Give it a shot.

You can check out all the parameters accepted by `query_posts` on the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: That works! Thanks so much! Question: $query is global variable right? Is it a handler of the query object? If so how come you didn't use it inside the function? Shouldn't it be $query->query_posts() instead?

Comment: oops.  the $query handler shouldn't be passed to the function.  That was an older idea I had.  sorry for the mistake.  I've edited the answer to remove.  But yes, my understanding is that $query holds the $query object.  But no, you don't need to use it like you've shown.  query_posts is a template tag like the_content().

Comment: see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query for information on $query and $WP_Query as a whole.  It can be helpful to manipulate the main query directly before it is run, sometimes.  query_posts runs a second query with the string you provide.  If you find yourself NEVER using the default main query and constantly making your own queries, you might want to learnhow to modify the main query by working directly with the functions of the $WP_Query class directly.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Thematic, so I browsed the documentation wiki at http://themeshaper.com/thematic/guide/.  I couldn't find the action you reference there.  Was it removed from the current version of the framework?

Create a simple "hellow world" function to test if the hook is broken vs your code being broken.

```
function hello_world(){
   echo "hello world";
}

add_action('thematic_above_indeloop', 'show_single_post');
```

If you see "hello world" on your homepage, you'll know the hook is working.  If not, you can be sure (as you probably already are) that your show_single_post function isn't broken.

Comment: Nope, it is present in the actual theme. That wiki is not complete. And yes your sample hook does work but unfortunately mine doesn't still. No one so far at their forums has an idea of what's wrong. That action hook seems to be troublesome...